# PostgreSQL. Можно ли очистить очень большую таблицу, если на диске нет места?

Tags: postgresql, администрирование

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке.
PostgreSQL 10. Есть большая таблица на несколько десятков гигабайт и несколько сотен миллионов записей. А вот места на диске совсем нет (пару сотен мегабайт).

Есть ли какие-нибудь колдовские заклинания, чтобы из этой таблички почистить все или часть записей, не имея свободного места?

Comment: удалять данные порциями.

Comment: @Novitskiy Denis, да я бы с удовольствием ) Но `DELETE` место не освобождает, а для `VACUUM FULL` опять нужно место. Замкнутый круг О_о

Comment: Команда TRUNCATE быстро удаляет все строки из набора таблиц. Она действует так же, как безусловная команда DELETE для каждой таблицы, но гораздо быстрее, так как она фактически не сканирует таблицы. Более того, она немедленно высвобождает дисковое пространство, так что выполнять операцию VACUUM после неё не требуется.

Comment: только truncate удалит сразу все данные из таблицы, без возможности что-то сохранить.

Comment: `DELETE` не освобождает место **в файловой системе**, а вот в БД -- очень даже. Вам "очистить" нужно для записи в эти же таблицы новых записей, так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, колдовские заклинания есть.

С полной очисткой таблицы справится `truncate`, требующий на диске только несколько десятков килобайт (под новую пустую таблицу, индексы, да занести информацию в WAL), но только полная очистка.

Если необходимо удалить не всё, но места нет - то необходимо делать:

- `delete` всего более ненужного
- `vacuum tablename`
- пустые `update` нужных строк частями, ничего на самом деле не изменяющие

  ```
   update tablename set column=column where ...
  ```
- такие update пометят строки удалёнными где те были и создадут копию в начале таблицы
- последующий `vacuum tablename` сможет возвращать место операционной системе если в конце таблицы остались только пустые страницы без живых данных

Основной фокус - придумать как перемещать только строки из конца таблицы. Индексы же только перестраивать. Можно через удаление и построение обратно, раз всё равно авария и места для работы нет.

Проблема у этого метода если у вас распухла не сама табличка, а её TOAST часть. Тогда таким способом не лечится.

---

Существует специально обученный `perl` скрипт [`pgcompacttable`](https://github.com/dataegret/pgcompacttable) специально написанной для сжатия таблиц в условиях недостатка дискового места и автоматизирующий описанные манипуляции манипуляции.

Comment: Да, `TRUNCATE` - это то, что нужно! Данные в таблице были не нужны.